# I want to fire a JSON variable stored in a JS file into an HTML file and loop over the contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am stuck on a problem where I have some JSON data stored in a variable that is defined within a function. Thus to access the JSON data, I would first need to make the function call. My function is as follows:

```
    viewDeposits: function() {
        var deposits = [];
        App.contracts.BOKCoin.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            bokcoinInstance = instance;
            return bokcoinInstance.depositCount();
        }).then(async function(depositCount) {
            var count = depositCount.toNumber();
            console.log(count);
            for(var i=1; i<=count; i++) {
                var x = await bokcoinInstance.deposits(i);
                deposits.push(x);
            }
            console.log(deposits);

            //send deposits to an html as an id 
            $('#deposits').html(deposits);
            return deposits;
        });
    }
```

Next, I want to call this function and store in a variable in a .HTML file and loop through its contents. I am being able to store the return object into a variable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You want to export `viewDeposits` to JSON, and save it in an HTML file so that you can load it and call it in the browser, is that correct?

Comment: yes, return the data of viewDeposits function to a variable and use this variable in HTML. Not explicitly make a JSON file